# Show that $\sum^{6}_{i=1} a_{i}=\frac{15}{2}$ and $ \sum^{6}_{i=1} a^{2}_{i}=\frac{45}{4} \implies \prod_{i=1}^{6} a_{i} \leq \frac{5}{2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

Let $a_{i}$, $1 \leq i \leq 6,$ be real numbers such that

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.2 in}\sum^{6}_{i=1} a_{i}=\frac{15}{2}\;\;$ and $\;\;\displaystyle\sum^{6}_{i=1} a^{2}_{i}=\frac{45}{4}$.

Prove that $\hspace{.15 in}\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{6} a_{i} \leq \frac{5}{2} $.

---

I was thinking if I consider the first summation and extended it, it going be pretty long which $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}+a_{6}= \frac{15}{2}$ and the second one like $a^{2}_{1}+a^{2}_{2}+a^{2}_{3}+a^{2}_{4}+a^{2}_{5}+a^{2}_{6}= \frac{45}{4}$. But I do not think this is the shortest of doing that, I am wondering if someone would be able to give me a hint so I can think better than this. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how much this helps, but if you write $a_i={3\over2}(1-b_i)$, the two equalities become $$b_1+\cdots+b_6=1$$ and $$b_1^2+\cdots+b_6^2=1$$  The second inequality implies $|b_i|\le1$ for all $i$, which implies the $a_i$'s are all non-negative (so an AGM approach is at least feasible).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Calculus of Variations approach. Perhaps not terribly elegant, but it works.
$$
\sum_{j=1}^6a_j=\frac{15}2\implies\sum_{j=1}^6\delta a_j=0\tag{1}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^6a_j^2=\frac{45}4\implies\sum_{j=1}^6a_j\delta a_j=0\tag{2}
$$
To maximize $\prod\limits_{j=1}^6a_j$, we want
$$
\sum_{j=1}^6\frac{\delta a_j}{a_j}=0\tag{3}
$$
for all variations under the conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$. Linearity implies that there are constants $b$ and $c$ so that
$$
\frac1{a_j}=b+ca_j\tag{4}
$$
Multiplying $(4)$ by $a_k$ and shuffling yields
$$
ca_j^2+ba_j-1=0\tag{5}
$$
Equation $(5)$ implies that there are only two possible values for $a_j$, $h$ and $k$. All of the $a_j$ cannot be equal since then $(1)$ implies $a_j=\frac54$, which does not satisfy $(2)$.

Thus, we have $3$ cases:
$$
h+5k=\frac{15}2\quad\text{and}\quad h^2+5k^2=\frac{45}4\implies(h,k)\in\left\{\left(0,\frac32\right),\left(\frac52,1\right)\right\}\tag{6}
$$
This gives products of $0$ and $\frac52$.
$$
2h+4k=\frac{15}2\quad\text{and}\quad2h^2+4k^2=\frac{45}4\implies(h,k)=\left(\frac{5\pm\sqrt{10}}4,\frac{10\mp\sqrt{10}}8\right)\tag{7}
$$
This gives products of $\frac{125(247\pm14\sqrt{10})}{16384}$.
$$
3h+3k=\frac{15}2\quad\text{and}\quad3h^2+3k^2=\frac{45}4\implies(h,k)=\left(\frac{5+\sqrt5}4,\frac{5-\sqrt5}4\right)\tag{8}
$$
This gives a product of $\frac{125}{64}$.

---

The greatest of these products is $\frac52$ given by the second solution in $(6)$: $\left\{\frac52,1,1,1,1,1\right\}$.

Therefore,
$$
\prod_{j=1}^6a_j\le\frac52\tag{9}
$$

Comment: would you explain how did you get the very first formula. Have used Kronecker delta. If so, would you please show me how. Thank you !

Comment: @ADAM: the $\delta$ is a variational delta, not a Kronecker delta. It represents an instantaneous change in that variable. Since $\sum_{j=1}^6a_j=\frac{15}2$, the sum of any variations must vanish; i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^6\delta a_j=0$, or the sum would vary.

Comment: Sounds great! Would you refer an article or a book might help me out in this matter. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

For any one of the variables, we have from CS inequality:
$$5\left(\frac{45}4-a_i^2 \right) \geqslant \left(\frac{15}2-a_i \right)^2 \implies 0 \leqslant a_i \leqslant  \frac52$$

If any $a_i = 0$ we clearly have a minimum, so all the variables are positive, and it is enough to show $\exists a, b \in \mathbb R$ s.t. $\forall x \in (0, \frac52]$.
$$f(x) = \left(\tfrac16\log \tfrac52- \log x \right)+a(x-\tfrac54) + b(x^2 - \tfrac{15}8) \geqslant 0$$

A little investigation shows $a = \frac73 - \frac89\log \frac52, \quad b = -\frac23 + \frac49\log \frac52 $ fit the bill, and equality is iff $x \in \{1, \frac52\}$.

Comment: the last statement is not true.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Not sure what you mean. Do you find other points where $f(x)=0$ in the interval?

Comment: yes, you are [right](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Cleft(%5Ctfrac16%5Clog+%5Ctfrac52-+%5Clog+x+%5Cright)%2B(7%2F3-8%2F9log(5%2F2))(x-%5Ctfrac54)+%2B+(-2%2F3%2B4%2F9log(5%2F2))(x%5E2+-+%5Ctfrac%7B15%7D8)%3D0,+x%3E0)

Comment: Would you please explain how did you set up your cauchy - schwarz inq.

Comment: Let $i=6$, then it is exactly $(1+1+1+1+1)(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_5^2)\geqslant (a_1+a_2+...a_5)^2$.  Now simplify using the constraints the terms in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The feasible set $S$ is the transversal intersection of a $5$-sphere and a hyperplane in ${\mathbb R}^6$, hence a $4$-sphere, in particular: a smooth compact manifold. The function $p({\bf a}):=\prod_{i=1}^6 a_i$ assumes its maximum on $S$ in one or several conditionally stationary points of $p$. It follows that such maximum points will be brought to the fore using Lagrange's method. Therefore we  set up the "Lagrangian"
$$\Phi:=p-\lambda\sum_i a_i-\mu\sum_i a_i^2$$
and look at the equations
$${\partial \Phi\over\partial a_i}={p\over a_i}-\lambda -2\mu a_i=0\qquad(1\leq i\leq 6)\ .$$
Since at the maximum points all $a_i$ have to be $\ne0$ this implies
$$p-\lambda a_i-2\mu a_i^2=0\qquad(1\leq i\leq 6)\ .$$
This is saying that at the maximum points all $a_i$ are solutions of one and the same at most quadratic equation. It follows that at most two different values $a_i$ occur at such points. We therefore have to consider for $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ the equations
$$r a_1+(6-r)a_2={15\over2},\qquad r a_1^2+(6-r)a_2^2={45\over4}\ ,$$
and have to check which case leads to the largest value of $p$. This amounts to the analysis conducted by @robjohn in his "variational" answer. I won't repeat it here.

Comment: Is $r$ restricted to being in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$b_i=a_i-\dfrac54,$$
then
$$\sum_{i=1}^6b_i=\sum_{i=1}^6a_i-6\cdot\dfrac54 = 0,$$
$$\sum b_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^6a_i^2 - \dfrac52\sum_{i=1}^6a_i+\dfrac{25}{16}\cdot6 = \dfrac{15}8,$$
and we can seach for conditional maximum of
$$\prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right).$$
Then we can use the Lagrange multipliers method.

For that, let search the greatest value of function 
$$f(\vec b, \lambda,\mu) = \prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right) + \lambda\sum_{i=1}^6b_i+\mu\left(\sum_{i=1}^6b_i^2-\dfrac{15}8\right),$$
the stationery points of which accords to zero derivatives
$f'_{b_k}=0,\ f'_\lambda=0,\ f'_\mu=0,$ or
$$\begin{cases}
\left(b_k+\dfrac54\right)^{-1}\prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right) + \lambda + 2\mu b_k = 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i \ = \ 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i^2\ - \ \dfrac{15}8\ =\ 0\\[4pt]
k=1\dots6,
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right) + \lambda\left(b_k+\dfrac54\right) + 2\mu\left(b_k+\dfrac54\right)b_k = 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i \ = \ 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i^2\ = \ \dfrac{15}8\\[4pt]
k=1\dots6.
\end{cases}$$
Summation by $k$ for indexed equation gives
$$6\prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right) + \lambda\dfrac{15}2 + \mu\dfrac{15}4 = 0,$$
or
$$\prod_{i=1}^6\left(b_i+\dfrac54\right) + \lambda\dfrac54 + \mu\dfrac58 = 0,$$
so we have
$$\begin{cases}
\lambda b_k + 2\mu\left(b_k^2+\dfrac54b_k-\dfrac5{16}\right) = 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i \ = \ 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i^2\ = \ \dfrac{15}8\\[4pt]
k=1\dots6.
\end{cases}$$
Values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ can be arbitrary, but the roots production still constant. So
$$\begin{cases}
(b_k=n)\vee(b_k=p)\\[4pt]
np=-\dfrac5{16}\\[4pt]
n<0,\ p>0\\[4pt] 
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i \ = \ 0\\[4pt]
\sum_{i=1}^6\ b_i^2\ = \ \dfrac{15}8\\[4pt]
k=1\dots6,
\end{cases}$$
and for $b_1\leq b_2 \leq b_3 \leq b_4 \leq b_5 \leq b_6$ we have:
$$\left[\begin{split}
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=n<0,\quad &6n=0,\quad &6n^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt]
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=n<0,\quad b_6=p=-\dfrac5{16n},\quad &5n=\dfrac5{16n},\quad &5n^2+p^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=n<0,\quad b_5=b_6=p=-\dfrac5{16n},\quad &4n=2\dfrac5{16n},\quad &4n^2+2p^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=n<0,\quad b_4=b_5=b_6=p=-\dfrac5{16n},\quad &3n=3\dfrac5{16n},\quad &3n^2+3p^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=n<0,\quad b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=p=-\dfrac5{16n},\quad &2n=4\dfrac5{16n},\quad &2n^2+4p^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=n<0,\quad b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=p=-\dfrac5{16n},\quad &n=5\dfrac5{16n},\quad &n^2+5p^2=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=p>0,\quad &6p=0,\quad &6p^2=\dfrac{15}8, 
\end{split}\right.$$
or
$$\left[\begin{split}
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=n=0,\quad &6\cdot0=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=n=-\dfrac14<0,\quad b_6=p=\dfrac54,\quad &5\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac{25}{16}=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=n=-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}},\quad b_5=b_6=p=\sqrt{\dfrac58},\quad &4\dfrac5{32}+2\dfrac58=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=-\dfrac{\sqrt5}4,\quad b_4=b_5=b_6=\dfrac{\sqrt5}4,\quad &3\dfrac5{16}+3\dfrac5{16}=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=b_2=n=-\dfrac{\sqrt5}2,\quad b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=\dfrac{\sqrt5}8,\quad &2\dfrac54+4\dfrac5{64}=\dfrac{15}8\\[4pt] 
&b_1=n=-\dfrac54,\quad b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=p=\dfrac14,\quad &\dfrac{25}{16}+5\dfrac1{16}=\dfrac{15}8\\ 
&b_1=b_2=b_3=b_4=b_5=b_6=p=0,\quad &6\cdot0=\dfrac{15}8, 
\end{split}\right.$$
Some systems are incompatible.

Therefore, the greatest value of goal production achieves in one of the points of the set
$$\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\[10pt]b_2\\[10pt]b_3\\[10pt]b_4\\[10pt]b_5\\[10pt]b_6\end{pmatrix}
\in\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac14\\-\dfrac14\\-\dfrac14\\-\dfrac14\\-\dfrac14\\\dfrac54\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}}\\-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}}\\-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}}\\-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}}\\\sqrt{\dfrac58}\\\sqrt{\dfrac58}\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\-\dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\-\dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\ \dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\\dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\\dfrac{\sqrt5}4\\\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac54\\\dfrac14\\\dfrac14\\\dfrac14\\\dfrac14\\ \dfrac14\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$
and is equal to
$$\max\left\{\left(-\dfrac14+\dfrac54\right)^5\left(\dfrac54+\dfrac54\right),
\left(-\sqrt{\dfrac5{32}}+\dfrac54\right)^4\left(\sqrt{\dfrac58}+\dfrac54\right)^2,
\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt5}4+\dfrac54\right)^3\left(\dfrac{\sqrt5}4+\dfrac54\right)^3,
\left(-\dfrac54+\dfrac54\right)\left(\dfrac14+\dfrac54\right)^5\right\}$$
$$=\max\left\{\dfrac52,\dfrac{125(247+14\sqrt{10})}{16384}
,\dfrac{125}{64},0\right\}=\dfrac52.$$

That means that
$$\boxed{\prod_{n=1}^6a_i \leq\dfrac52}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:** Consider the polynomial $$P\left(x\right)=x^{6}+\sum_{m=1}^{6}b_{m}x^{m-1}
 $$ where $b_{m}\in\mathbb{R}
 $ and assume that $a_{i},\, i=1,\dots,6
 $ are the roots of this polynomial. By the [Laguerre-Samuleson inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuelson%27s_inequality) we have that $$b_{1}=-\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}=-\frac{15}{2}
 $$ $$b_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{6}a_{i}^{2}=\frac{45}{4}
 $$ and $$-\frac{b_{1}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{6b_{2}-b_{1}^{2}}}{2}\leq a_{i}\leq-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+\frac{\sqrt{6b_{2}-b_{1}^{2}}}{2}\sqrt{5}\tag{1}
 $$ ($(1)$ and the other inequalities obviously hold for every polynomial of degree $n$) so in our case we have $$0\leq a_{i}\leq\frac{5}{2}
 $$ but this not ensure the inequality. So we have to recall [the Brunk's inequalities and Boyd-Hawkins inequalities](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stjensen/papers/shanejensen.mscthesis99.pdf). Let $$s=\frac{\sqrt{6b_{2}-b_{1}^{2}}}{2}.
 $$ If we assume that $$a_{1}\geq a_{2}\geq\dots\geq a_{6}
 $$ then $$-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+\frac{s}{\sqrt{5}}\leq a_{1}\leq-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+s\sqrt{5},\tag{2}
 $$ $$-\frac{b_{1}}{6}-s\sqrt{5}\leq a_{6}\leq-\frac{b_{1}}{6}-\frac{s}{\sqrt{5}}\tag{3}
 $$ and $$-\frac{b_{1}}{6}-s\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{6-k+1}}\leq a_{k}\leq-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+s\sqrt{\frac{6-k}{k}},\, k=2,\dots,5.\tag{4}
 $$ It is important to note that the equality holds in the RHS of $(2)$ if and only if the equality holds in the RHS of $(3)$ and this is equivalent to $$a_{1}=-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+s\sqrt{5}
 $$ $$a_{2}=\dots=a_{6}=-\frac{b_{1}}{6}-\frac{s}{\sqrt{5}}.
 $$ In this case the product is exactly $5/2$. In a similar way it is possible to prove that the equality in the RHS of $(4)$ holds if and only if$$a_{1}=\dots=a_{k}
 $$ $$a_{k+1}=\dots=a_{6}
 $$ hence $$a_{1}=\dots=a_{k}=-\frac{b_{1}}{6}+s\sqrt{\frac{6-k}{k}}
 $$ $$a_{k+1}=\dots=a_{6}=-\frac{b_{1}}{6}-s\sqrt{\frac{k}{6-k}}
 $$ and again if we maximize a root necessary the product is less or equal to $5/2$. This argument not consider all the possible cases but maybe it may be helpful for a complete proof.